# Angular plotly chart inside a material card not aligning correctly

Tags: angular, plotly.js

I have the following component html code using angular material to create a card. Inside the card I add a plotly chart.

```html
<mat-grid-tile [colspan]="(isHandset$ | async )? 1 : 1" [rowspan]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 1 : 2">
    <mat-card #activeDevices class="dashboard-card">
        <mat-card-header>
            <mat-card-title>
              Active Devices
            </mat-card-title>
        </mat-card-header>
        <mat-card-content class="dashboard-card-content">
            <plotly-plot [useResizeHandler]="true" [config]="plotlyData.configuration" [data]="activeDevicesPlotlyData" [layout]="layout"></plotly-plot>
        </mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>            
</mat-grid-tile>
```

The layout property is fixed `layout = {autosize: true}`. When startint the application and the component is loaded I get the following non aligned result:

[image: non aligned card with chart]

If I open and close the dev tools (pres F12) then the alignment is fixed:

[image: aligned card with chart]

Since I am a bit new to the angular and javascript world, why isn't plotly picking up the correct measurements of my card when the component is initialized?

Comment: set width of container class css `dashboard-card-content`

Comment: can you provide me with an example please?

Comment: worked adding the following `width: 90%` not qute sure why it doesn't work with larger percentage. But thanks a lot